Trying to make a bootable usb for Dell Wyse 3020 ARM device, but running into problems
I am using a Fedora VM (I have Windows on my PC) to try and create a bootable USB (16GB). I am following this guide.
However, I get "No U-Boot files found for olpc_xo175" when I perform this step:
arm-image-installer --resizefs --target=olpc_xo175 --media=/dev/sdx --image=Fedora-Minimal-armhfp-32-1.6-sda.raw.xz

And later when I run this step:
mkimage -A arm -O linux -C none -T ramdisk -d /mnt/efi/initramfs-* /mnt/efi/uInitrd

I get:
Can't open /mnt/efi/initramfs-*: No such file or directory

What can I do to fix this?
